# How can I add 'pages' in addition to 'tags' with acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby, tags, content-management-system, acts-as-taggable-on

I am just in the last few months learning Ruby from a client project, and have now decided to port my legacy CMS into Ruby.

I have successfully installed the gem and implemented acts-as-taggable-on with tags and taggings so that I have tags working in my Post controller.  I can add tags to my edit form, and they are linked in my posts as expected.

What I am hoping to do is use the enhanced features of acts-as-taggable-on to define another set of 'tags' which are actually pages.  In my current application I have a table called Pages, and the Posts have a field called PageID.  The Pages table holds the name of the page, as well as some config features for that page, such as layout and css.  Posts can only appear in the Page they were assigned/created from.

Since all Posts are stored in the same table, I was hoping to extend the acts-as-taggable-on to handle both my tagging and pages, if this makes sense.

I understand how the same tagging model can be extended to other controllers such as Photos, Video etc, but I am unsure how I would go about applying 2 different 'tagging' models to the same Controller.  If I don't use tagging for the pages, I am unsure about how I would define the 'pages' in a Ruby context, since I need the page names to be dynamic per user.  I understand theoretically how to do this in routes.rb but am stuck as how to define my pages.

Thanks for any help!  Let me know what .rb file code to post to illustrate what I am doing now.

Comment: Are you sure you'd be using the right tool for the job? Acts-as-taggable-on is great for handling tags, but it wasn't designed to handle other resource types. What features of acts-as-taggable-on do you need for pages and how would these features be better than building a `Page` model?

Comment: I am not sure actually, which is why I asked!  I understand that using it to define my pages would be a hack, but not sure of which approach to take.  The reason I can't use a normal 'Page' model is because the title of the page will change.

For example, every entry in my CMS is a Post already.  What I need to do is find a way to do the following:

Comment: site.com/ABOUT/postname or site.com/BLOG/postname - the first Page name needs to route to something.  If I understand, a Page model will be hardcoded so that I would need to have defined a controller for each page?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

Create two classes "Page" and "Post" that inherit from a base "UserContent" class. The "Page" and "Blog" classes would have to each have their own controller.

You could route to each of them with something like:

```
scope '/blog' do
  resources :posts
end

scope '/about' do
  resources :posts
end
```

To use the post name instead of an id, I would highly recommend you checkout **[stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex)** which will allow you to do just that. It will involve adding a url attribute to your models but I'll let you check out their documentation to find out how it all works. This should be the answer to your original question and it should be a better tool for dynamic page/post page names than acts-as-taggable-on.

This setup should give you `"site.com/about/page-name"` for pages and `"site.com/blog/post-name"` for posts.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback sir!  the stringex thing seems perfect, but the suggestion on the classes is actually still off a bit.  let me be more specific.  The CMS handles @ 100 sites, each site has 5-10 top level 'pages' which can be changed by the user.  So I am looking for a way to dynamically map the page name to something.  It seems that stringex will work good for this as well, just unsure of how to proceed.  Thanks again!